# Writing Stored Procedures in a Bash Script file

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in a bash script. 
This is the script file

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u $1 -p$2  -e " 
create database test;
use test;
DELIMITER $$; 
CREATE PROCEDURE test.createTables ()
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Employee (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100),
    Department varchar(200) NOT NULL
    );
END$$
"
```

Here $1 and $2 are the user and the password of the database respectively which I am passing as command-line arguments.
When I try to run the same commands in the MySQL console it works fine but when I am running the script file i am getting the following error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

Can someone point where I am going wrong?

Comment: Put the SQL in single quotes, not double quotes. `$$` is expanded by the shell in double quotes.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, but i am still getting the same error

Comment: You're setting the delimiter to `$$;` not `$$`. get rid of the extra `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `DELIMITER $$;` to `DELIMITER $$`. You don't need a `;` at the end of the `DELIMITER` directive; it's treating `;` as part of the delimiter string.

Also use single quotes around the string.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u $1 -p$2  -e '
create database test;
use androidcrashes;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test.createTables ()
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Employee (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100),
    Department varchar(200) NOT NULL
    );
END$$
'
```